# Number of perfect squares in $ 4^{6} \cdot 6^{7} \cdot 21^{8}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Why can't we use this approach:
rewriting, $2^{19} \cdot 7^{8} \cdot 3^{15}$, and then
using $(3\cdot 2)\cdot(4^9)\cdot(49^4)\cdot(9^7)$.
Hence, number of perfect squares is $10\cdot 5\cdot 8$.

The answer seems to differ.

Comment: Do you mean, number of perfect squares which divide $4^6\cdot6^7\cdot21^8$ without remainder?

Comment: @user371530 What is the given answer? It is not clear what "Number of perfect squares in" means.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you. If $n=4^{6} \cdot 6^{7} \cdot 21^{8}=2^{19}  \cdot 3^{15}\cdot 7^{8}$ then the number of perfect squares which divide $n$ is
$$(\lfloor 19/2\rfloor+1)\cdot (\lfloor 15/2\rfloor+1)\cdot (\lfloor 8/2\rfloor+1)=10\cdot  8\cdot 5=400.$$
What is the given answer? It is not clear what "Number of perfect squares in" means.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted:

$4^{6}\cdot6^{7}\cdot21^{8}=2^{\color\red{19}}\cdot3^{\color\green{15}}\cdot7^{\color\orange{8}}$

---

Any perfect square diving this number must be of the following type:

$(2^{0\text{ or }2\text{ or }\dots\text{ or }\lfloor\color\red{19}/2\rfloor\cdot2})\cdot(3^{0\text{ or }2\text{ or }\dots\text{ or }\lfloor\color\green{15}/2\rfloor\cdot2})\cdot(7^{0\text{ or }2\text{ or }\dots\text{ or }\lfloor\color\orange{8}/2\rfloor\cdot2})$

---

Hence the amount of perfect squares dividing this number is:

$(\lfloor\color\red{19}/2\rfloor+1)\cdot(\lfloor\color\green{15}/2\rfloor+1)\cdot(\lfloor\color\orange{8}/2\rfloor+1)=400$